# Springer Nature American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style

Tags: bibliographystyle, springernature

Kindly suggest which `.bst` file should match for the style `Springer Nature American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style`... Please advise

For more details https://typeset.io/formats/springer-nature/springer-nature-american-physical-society-aps-reference-style/d5b6e8aee1ee4160a6f368aedf1ea79c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are supposed to use the American Physical Society (APS) bib style along with the "Springer Journal" document class, give

  ```
  \documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}
  ```

  a try.
- If you wish to use the APS bib style *without* employing the "Springer Journal" document class, give

  ```
  \documentclass[<some-options>]{<some-class>}
  % ... (other preamble stuff)
  \bibliographystyle{sn-aps}
  ```

  a try. If you pursue this route, you'll probably also have to provide a dummy definition for the macro `\bibcommenthead` that's used by the Springer Journal bib styles. E.g., something such as `\def\bibcommenthead{}`.

Springer actually provides an email address for answering authors' LaTeX- and BibTeX-related questions. It is `LaTeXSupport@spi-global.com`.